# (Working) @media query for iPhone 6 (phonegap)?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, cordova, media

I'm trying to update a Phonegap (3.4.0) app by expanding my CSS file for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, however, the media queries don't seem to work properly (only testing in Simulator so far, 8.0 / 550.1). In particular, any tests using `resolution`, `device-width`, `max-device-width` etc. seem to fail. I tried to figure out what's going on by testing the conditions one by one. Any tests for `device-aspect ratio` and `resolution` failed for iPhone 6. For `device-width` and `device-height` I tried both the actual pixel values (1334px, 750px) as well as the virtual dimensions (667px, 375px).  `device-height` seems to work,  `device-width` doesn't (app is in portrait mode):

```
@media screen 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) /* this one works */
and (resolution: 326dpi) /* fails */
and (min-device-width: 375px) /* fails, passes up to 320px ?!? */
and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) /* fails, so does 9/16 ..? */
and (min-device-height: 375px) /* works, but height only */
and (max-device-height: 667px) /* works, but height only */
{
...
}
```

Not sure if this is a Webkit / phongap or iOS8 issue (or if I overlooked something). Did anyone figure this out / have a (working) iPhone 6 query? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your app have the correct splash screen images for the iPhone 6 resolutions? If not, the device reports a smaller screen size (i.e. it ends up just scaling your app up to fit)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that link between launch image and (reported) screen resolution. After creating a fresh asset catalog it works now :-)